# Code to read the file and pass the bytes[]

Tags: coldfusion

So ColdFusion need to read the file and pass the bytes[]. 
once i read file using `<cffile action="read">` then how to convert content to `base64`? i know there is function `toBase64` but this takes string or binary data only.

Comment: A google search on "cold fusion read file" will lead you to the code for reading files with ColdFusion.

Comment: You are asking about a few different steps in a multi-part process. Which part of this process can you not do? Where's the code you've tried, and what of your own research have you done? This needs to go into the question so as to demonstrate you've actually tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: You cannot pass a byte array via HTTP, you have to encode it (usually done in either Hex or Base64). What does your webservice expect i.e. is able to decode?

Comment: I have researched that cffile action = "read" ,Reads a file on the server and does it reads all kind of files such as (word,pdf,excel) or only text file?

Comment: I have researched that cffile action = "read" ,Reads a file on the server and does it reads all kind of files such as (word,pdf,excel) or only text file?       <cffile action = "read"  
             file = "c:\web\message.txt"  
            variable = "Message"  and also i have looked into cffile action = "readBinary" does this reads all kind of files such as (word,pdf,excel).   1) If both actions doesnt support all types of files can you tell me which action reads all types of files? 2) Once i read the file pass the data as bytes[]

Comment: Can i create a java object and use it in coldfusion like below please help              pathOb = createObject("java", "java.nio.file.Paths");
files = createObject("java", "java.nio.file.Files");

path = pathOb.get("file");
data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

Comment: *You cannot pass a byte array via HTTP, you have to encode it* No, web services can also accept pure binary.

Comment: @pran - You can, but it is not necessary.  The two cffile actions are not the same. If you read the documentation it says: `<cffile action="read" ..>`  *Read[s] a text file;*.  As the name implies, `<cffile action="readBinary"...>` - *Reads a binary file.* If you need the binary, then use "readBinary".  Also, your original question is very broad, and likely to be closed, please move some of your comments above into the question itself.

Comment: ok i got it. once i read file using cffile action" read" then how to convert content to base64? i know there is function  toBase64 but this takes string or binary data only.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, ["....as the name implies, `<cffile action="readBinary"...>` reads a binary file. If you need the binary, then use "readBinary".](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060947/code-to-read-the-file-and-pass-the-bytes#comment53954693_33060947).

Comment: Also, the original post said your web service accepts `byte[]`. The update says you need a "base64" string. Two very different things. Which one is the web service expecting?